SQLite is not displaying decimal values
I am using SQLite and have the following query:
select round((10/3), 5) as example

And it displays the following result:
example|
-------+
3.0    |

I've tried several approaches such as casting to float, rounding, and multiplying the field times 1.0; but nothing seems to work.
Does anyone know why this happens? And how to resolve it...
Thank you in advance.

You're using integer division. 10/3 returns 3. If you want to divide two integer fields multiply one of them with 1.0 before dividing

SQLite assumes an integer operation.
You could try adding .0 to either 3.0 or 10.0:
select round((10/3.0), 5) as example


Not just SQLite, all databases will use integer division between integers.
